# Need MYSQL two tables database query solution

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I have the following two tables:
Table 1 has all the orders and Table 2 the productions. I need a query that sums table2 R-001 amounts and subtract from it Table 1 close amounts.

Table 1

| barcode | amount | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| R-001 | 10 | open |
| R-001 | 10 | close |
| R-001 | 20 | open |

Table 2

| barcode | amount |
| --- | --- |
| R-001 | 2 |
| R-001 | 3 |
| R-001 | 10 |

Result looking for:

| R-001 |
| --- |
| 5 |

How can I get this result?

Comment: Welcome to SO. This site is not for getting plain solutions to copy paste, rather to give you hints to the right direction. So maybe post the code you already have or what you already tried and then we can help you properly

Comment: The question doesn't make sense as asked, since the OP seems to imply that the rows need to be selected by ordering -- that doesn't exist in relational databases. Voting to close.

Comment: the relation is clearly based on barcode columns as explain by OP .. anyway you need a join and group by

Comment: are there always close records for the barcode you are looking up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your desired results are somewhat confusing since you would not have the value of a row as a column alias, but perhaps this is what you are after:

```
select t2.barcode, 
    Sum(t2.amount) - coalesce((
        select Sum(t1.amount) 
        from t1
        where t1.barcode=t2.barcode and t1.state='close'
    ),0) as Amount
from t2  
where t2.barcode='R-001'
group by t2.barcode
```

Comment: Hi thx! If I want to show only the result of R-001 barcode and the difrent barcodes not?

Comment: Just add a `where` criteria. I have added above.

Comment: if there are no t1 close records, this returns null; coalesce the subquery to 0

Comment: @ysth good spot, amended 

Answer (score 0):

You need a join based on subqiery for amount of table 2 and table 1 group by barcode

```
select t1.barcode,  t2.t2_amount - sum(t2.amount )
from table1 t1
inner join  (
    barcode, sum(amount ) t2_amount
    from table1
    group by barcode
) t2 on t1.barcode = t2.barcode
where t1.state ='close'
group by t1.barcode,  t2.t2_amount
```